# Incorrect Peer Dependency Ag Grid React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

How do I fix the following warning that I'm getting while running `yarn install`.

```
warning "@next-ui/custom-grid" > @next-ui/dep-components-custom-grid@2.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "ag-grid-react@28.2.0"
warning "@next-ui/custom-grid" > @next-ui/dep-components-custom-grid@2.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "ag-grid-enterprise@28.2.0"
warning "@next-ui/custom-grid" > @next-ui/dep-components-custom-grid@2.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@mui/material@5.11.16"
```

Due to this, I'm getting the following error on my main app

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@next-ui/dep-components-custom-grid/index.js 8:0-52
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ag-grid-enterprise/dist/styles/ag-grid.css' in 'C:\Users\ttm2\Source\appdev\TadaUI\node_modules\@next-ui\dep-components-custom-grid'

ERROR in ./node_modules/@next-ui/dep-components-custom-grid/index.js 9:0-60
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ag-grid-enterprise/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css' in 'C:\Users\ttm2\Source\appdev\TadaUI\node_modules\@next-ui\dep-components-custom-grid'                                                                                                          .14.9".

ERROR in ./node_modules/@next-ui/dep-components-custom-grid/index.js 10:0-65 
--------------------------------------------------------------------] 0/1766
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ag-grid-enterprise/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine-dark.css' in 'C:\Users\ttm2\Source\appdev\TadaUI\node_modules\@next-ui\dep-components-custom-grid'
```

There is a missing `styles` folder inside the `node_modules/ag-grid-enterprise/dist` and when I pasted them from other project, everything works fine. But if I deploy this to cloud, then I might face this issue again.

How do I fix this? Any help would be appreciated.